# Chocolate covered cookies stuck to cooling rack

Tags: chocolate, cookies, glaze

I have some glazed chocolate cookies that I accidentally put on a cooling rack to let the chocolate glaze cool off, but now the chocolate glaze is completely stuck to the cooling rack. Any ideas on how to get the cookies off the rack without destroying them?

Answer (score 7):

Turn the rack upside down, suspend it so that there is about a quarter inch between the cookie and the surface it will fall onto when it detaches from the rack, then heat the chocolate underside of the cookie (which is now the top that you can see because the rack is upside down) with a hairdryer/low temp heat gun so that it melts enough for the rack metal to move through the chocolate and for the cookie to fall/push off the rack

Answer (score 2):

Get a sharp knife and gently cut the cookies off the rack.

Push the knife flat along the cooling rack and ideally cut just towards the center of your cookies - this may need some manoeuvering if your cookies are pretty close together.

If you are dealing with a glaze that melts, heat your knife. A tall glass with hot water helps, for example. But wipe the blade before using.

Comment: Yes, I tried that with a hot spatula, but it didn't work. What did work was just holding the rack over my gas stove burners for a few seconds, then picking the cookies off and flipping them over onto parchment paper. Chocolate mess dripping all over the place, but I pretty much saved the cookies!

Comment: @Frank, just post an answer to your own question. That's perfectly ok here. Welcome to the site, btw.! Don't forget to take the [tour] and browse our [help] to learn more about the site and the Stack Exchange system in general.

Comment: freezing contracts metal and cookies are more stable to brute force but who has freezer space for a rack?